# Unable to click dynamically changing id button created using span and not to select option from dropdown list

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

Below is the span that I'm trying to click. The number sequence in the id is changing dynamically.

```
<span id="actionsButton__o3uid5535_label" class="dijitReset dijitInline dijitButtonText" data-dojo-attach-point="containerNode,_popupStateNode">Actions</span>
```

So I tried to use..

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
WebElement el = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath(".//span[contains(text(), 'Actions')]")));
        ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("arguments[0].click()", el);
```

but no success.

Can someone please help me in finding solution for this issue

Comment: What do you mean no success?? And why are you not using `el.click()`...???

Comment: I'm not able to click Actions using my code. I already tried using el.click(), it didn't work

Comment: What do you mean didn't work?? Is there any exception??